# Double colon `::` notation in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting

I have picked up someone's code, the following is a part of a `WHERE` clause. What does the double colon indicate here?

```
b.date_completed >  a.dc::date + INTERVAL '1 DAY 7:20:00'
```

Comment: from [PostgreSQL 9.4.5 Documentation - Chapter 4. SQL Syntax - 4.2.9. Type Casts](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS)

Comment: More comprehensive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676816/postgres-data-type-cast/13676871#13676871

Answer (score 98):

It varies based on RDBMS, but if I guess right, that's PostgreSQL, in which case the `::` converts `a.dc` to a date type of `date`.

In other flavors...

In MS SQL Server 2000:

> For built-in user-defined functions
>   that return a table, the function name
>   must be specified with a leading
>   double colon (::) to distinguish it
>   from user-defined functions that are
>   not built-in. It also must be
>   specified as a one-part name with no
>   database or owner qualifications. For
>   example: SELECT * FROM
>   ::fn_helpcollations() b.. For built-in
>   user-defined functions that return a
>   scalar value, the function name must
>   be specified as a one-part name (do
>   not specify database or owner). Do not
>   specify a leading double colon (::).

In MS SQL Server 2005:

> Double-colons are no longer required
>   for UDFs that return a table.

However...

> Double-colons are required in SQL
>   Server 2005 when granting permissions
>   on schemas, certificates, endpoints,
>   and a few other securables.

As well as...

> When using User-Defined Types, static
>   methods of the type must be called
>   using the double-colon syntax.

Sources: [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213008%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) and [Kalen Delaney's Blog](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2006/09/06/186.aspx)

Comment: I came across this syntax used with a UDF in the SQL 2008 MCTS practice exam, it's not mentioned anywhere in the book! Thanks for explaining

Answer (score 48):

In this case, it is a cast to a date type.  :: is a type cast that can also be represented as CAST(expression AS type).

Comment: If you know that for sure then maybe you know what RDBMS this script is for?

Comment: Looks like PostgreSQL to me.  Do you know of any alternatives that would have the same syntax?

Comment: I know of some RDBMSes that support the double colon notation, and I know of some others that feature the `INTERVAL` support. This is the first piece of code I've ever seen that combines both. I was just curious. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 39):

It is a `CAST` operation(cast to a date type).

Example:

`SELECT now()::timestamp(0);`

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 
    CAST (now() AS timestamp(0));
```

They both result in casting `now()` to `timestamp` in the following format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: Another simple example might be: `select 1.2::integer`, which will output result as `1`.

Answer (score 3):

It is probably a cast, converting `a.dc` to type `date`.

IBM Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) would work that way - but the INTERVAL notation at the end is not valid for IDS, so presumably this is in fact another DBMS (probably [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)).