# postgres sql, date_trunc without extra zeroes

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, date-format

This is an excerpt from my sql query

```
SELECT
date_trunc(
    'day',
    to_timestamp(requests.date_created)
)AS DAY,
```

this is my output 
`2013-02-04 00:00:00+00`

I want this to be just
`2013-02-04`

how do I get the desired result?

Comment: The trouble is probably from using a timestamp instead of a date. Try using `to_date`. What type of data does the `day` attribute hold that is making this function necessary?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

please, try

```
SELECT date_trunc(...)::date;
```

Comment: this worked for me, I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when it lets me

Comment: To anyone wondering, the :: operator is type casting (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758523/2087198)

Answer (score 5):

You can use to_date to specify your date format

```
TO_DATE(date_col, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Comment: I think this works in Redshift, but it doesn't work in vanilla Postgres.