# PostgreSQL: View adjust Date based on hour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a view that queries sales data into a condensed table which sums net_sales for each location.  The problem i have is when there are sales after midnight.  My code is grouping by Date so any sales after midnight are listed on the wrong day.

```
SELECT r.name AS store,
r.id,
date(se.date) AS date,
c.dow,
c.week,
c.period,
c.year,
sum(se.netsales) AS net_sales,
sum(se.numberofguests) AS guest_count
FROM sales_employee se
JOIN restaurants r ON r.locationid::text = se.location
JOIN calendar c ON c.date = date(se.date)
GROUP BY r.name, r.id, (date(se.date)), c.dow, c.week, c.period, c.year
ORDER BY (date(se.date)) DESC, r.name;
```

There is another column in sales_employee (orderhour) which is bigint from 0-23. The system shuts down at 4am so what i need to do is collect sales from orderhour[4] through orderhour[3] and apply the sales of orderhour[0-3] to the previous date.  Can that be done?

Comment: 1) The 0-3 hours are in the correct day, they are just not in the period you want covered. 2) I don't understand this *... from orderhour[4] through orderhour[3] and apply the sales of orderhour[0-3]  ...*.

Comment: The 0-3 have a date of 2024-01-01 when i want them to be 2023-12-31 since thats the days sales i want to sum.

Comment: orderhour-3 goes up to 3:59am.  at 4:00am our system shutsdown and closes the day.  I am trying to sum the sales from when we open at 11:00am till when we close after midnight and the system shuts down at 4:00am

Comment: So your period is 11:00 day1 - 3:59 day2. Pretending 3:59 day2 = 3.59 day1 is not going to work, if for no other reason then it walks over the day1 - (day1 - 1) day period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried modifying your `SQL` query to allocate sales made between midnight and 4 AM to the previous day, using a `CASE` statement to adjust the date based on the `orderhour` column. Give it a try

```
  SELECT
        r.name AS store,
        r.id,
        CASE 
            WHEN se.orderhour >= 4 THEN date(se.date)
            ELSE date(se.date) - interval '1 day'
        END AS adjusted_date,
        c.dow,
        c.week,
        c.period,
        c.year,
        sum(se.netsales) AS net_sales,
        sum(se.numberofguests) AS guest_count
    FROM
        sales_employee se
    JOIN
        restaurants r ON r.locationid::text = se.location
    JOIN
        calendar c ON c.date = CASE 
                                 WHEN se.orderhour >= 4 THEN date(se.date)
                                 ELSE date(se.date) - interval '1 day'
                               END
    GROUP BY
        r.name, r.id, adjusted_date, c.dow, c.week, c.period, c.year
    ORDER BY
        adjusted_date DESC, r.name;
```

Comment: This appears to have worked.  However, the sales after midnight have disappeared, so the total for 12/31 is incorrect but 1/1 is correct.  At first glance i don't think its with this code.  I will followup.

Comment: This did work perfectly.  Thanks for your help, i was able to find a few more bugs during this process.

Comment: I have one more issue.  This is giving me a date like "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00" .  all i want is "yyyy-mm-dd".  I tried "date_trunc" but cannot get it to work.

Comment: date_trunc solved here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14691287/6814989

Answer (score 0):

Whereever you use the date, use:

```
(datecolumn - interval '4 hours')::date
```

instead.  Subtracting four hours moves transactions between 00:00 and 04:00 to one day earlier.  So for example:

```
JOIN calendar c ON c.date = date(se.date - interval '4 hours')
```

Comment: I tried this and the view came up empty:   this is how the code looks:  JOIN calendar c ON c.date = (date(se.date) - '04:00:00'::interval)

Comment: What happens when you cast it back to date?  `JOIN calendar c ON c.date = (date(se.date) - '04:00:00'::interval)::date`

Comment: that gave me an syntax error but i tried just moving the close parenthesis to the end and while it still shows the date as 2024-01-01 the "dow" changed from 6 to 5 which i could work with:   JOIN calendar c ON c.date = date(se.date - '04:00:00'::interval)

Comment: its changing the items its joining but not the actual date.  Im trying to change the date under the select part.

Comment: It looks like `date(x)` is the same as `x::date`.  So what happens when you select `date(se.date - '04:00:00'::interval) AS date`?

Comment: I think i am going to have to  change my app code to use dow.  Changing the view code has locked up my database and crashed the app.