# What does "::" mean in a SQL context?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

What does the "::" syntax mean in SSDT error message SQL71561? For example:

> SQL71561: View: [dbo].[V_RPT_MART_SIGNALS] contains an unresolved reference to an object.Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: 
>   [SSISDB].[CATALOG].[EXECUTIONS].[EXECUTION_ID] or 
>   [SSISDB].[CATALOG].[EXECUTIONS].[TM]::[EXECUTION_ID]

This seems like such a strange syntax to see in in a SQL context, I can't believe I can't find it documented anywhere. (I've found that doing an online search for "::" doesn't work too well!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Double colon (::) notation in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758499/double-colon-notation-in-sql)

Comment: @Adelphia that question is for Postgres. The OP here is using SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specific case there

```
  [SSISDB].[CATALOG].[EXECUTIONS].[TM]::[EXECUTION_ID]
```

The syntax would be database.schema.table_or_view.column::static_method_on_clr_type

The double colon is also used [in legacy syntax for some functions](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2006/09/06/186.aspx)

```
 SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

And in the grammar for `GRANT`, `REVOKE`, `DENY`. ([Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187940.aspx))

```
 GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA :: HumanResources TO guest;
```

Comment: So, it's not scope resolution operator as in my answer?

Comment: @Rahul No. The only valid interpretation and usage after a column name would be invoking a static method of a CLR type.

Comment: Hmm +1. Good to know. Deleting my answer.