# What does :: mean in ::BOOL?

Tags: sql, boolean, netezza

I have a SQL case statement and wanted to know what `::BOOL` means. In my example it is used in a case...when statement. Please guide me as to what it means in that context. My database is Netezza.

```
case
when...
then 't' ::BOOL.
```

Comment: I'm guessing your real question is what the double colon means - the BOOL is just a data type.  See this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758499/double-colon-notation-in-sql) for an answer.

Comment: I agree with @Dave.Gugg that this is probably a duplicate of that. Faisal should edit this question if they aren't really asking about the ::, but about the BOOL.

Answer (score 0):

That means "as BOOL"

`::` is a common way to cast types in SQL Dialects

Netezza uses 't' and 'f' as true and false, so your line just returns Boolean True.