# Can anyone explain :: meaning in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have below query which works properly but don't know meaning and use of `::` in postgresql.

```
select (
    select ( 
        case when 1 > 0 then 1::float / (
            select count(id) from transactions_products where transaction_id in (
            select id from transactions_transactions tt 
            where status = 3 and fi = 355 
                and (invoice_date >= 1420754400) 
                and (invoice_date <= 1421099999) 
                and (tt.division_id = 107) 
                and (tt.department_id = 210) 
        ) and is_vehicle = 1 
    )::float else 0 end)
 limit 1) as f_4
```

Comment: There's a few [related questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758499/double-colon-notation-in-sql) here, but they seem to relate to PostgreSQL.

Comment: When is 1 not greater than 0 ?

Comment: @Strawberry: on Tuesday afternoons, I believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758499/double-colon-notation-in-sql

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`::` is the [cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createcast.html) operator for PostgreSQL.

Comment: Is it not possible in mysql?

Comment: Yes - using [`cast()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

Comment: And CAST() is also standard SQL, works in many databases that support some form of SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Short, no-hassle answer: It casts the value to a float.

Comment: You might want to elaborate on your answer. It's not really useful to just say it casts the value. Why would you want to cast a value? Is there a better example of a use case?

Comment: I see what you mean, but then the post would just turn into a general discussion of the purpose, pros and cons of typecasting.

Comment: You don't need to go into that level of detail, just explain why you would use one or provide something for the OP to go on. You're assuming that everyone knows what casting is. Note the top answer has a link to more information.

Comment: That is indeed a better answer. Thank you for your feedback!