# How to type cast in sqlite3

Tags: sql, casting, sqlite

I ran sqlite3 on my command prompt and ran some basic SQL commands.

```
user@comp:~$ sqlite3  
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30  
Enter ".help" for instructions  
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"  
sqlite> CREATE TABLE A (a int, b text, c float);  
sqlite> INSERT INTO A(a,b,c) VALUES (1, '2', 3);  
sqlite> SELECT b::int+2 FROM A;
```

All of the lines work except for the last one, which gives the error: `

> Error: unrecognized token: ":"`

I was reading from this question ([Double colon (::) notation in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758499/double-colon-notation-in-sql)) that the double colon notation is a type-cast for SQL. Am I doing the operation wrong?

Comment: sqlite and Postgresql are 2 different things. The syntax they use is not portable. Only ANSI standard part.

Comment: How would you do it in sqlite?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `::` syntax is PostgreSQL specific. You could use ANSI standard instead:

```
SELECT CAST(b AS INT) + 2 AS alias
FROM A
```

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/a7a39/1/0)**